# Using mustache variable in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mustache

1. I am using mustache.js. My mustache variable is {{hotel_name}}
2. I assigned mustache variable to php as below

---

```
<?php 
    $fpname = '{{hotel_name}}'; 
    echo $fpname;
?>
```

**Output is** 'Eggless Blackforest Cake Half Kg'

3. Since length of the string is big i used substr as below

---

```
$fname = '<b>'.substr($fpname,0,10); if(strlen($fpname) > 10) $fname .= '...'; $fname .= '</b>';
```

**Output is as below**

Eggless Blackforest Cake Half Kg

Now my query is how can i show a part of the string ....

**Expected output is**

Eggless Bl...

Comment: Restrict to what??? you have already restricted to 10 char i think.

Comment: What do you mean by "restrict this string"? If you're concerned that your output hasn't changed, could it be that you're building the shorter string in $fname and still echoing $fpname? If not, I don't know what you're asking, please include what you expect the output to be.

Comment: mustache with substr function combination is not working, showing full string

Comment: Got the solution in script (mustache) i done hotel_name.substring(0,20), this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine,

```
$fpname = "Eggless Blackforest Cake Half Kg";

$fname = '<b>'.substr($fpname,0,10); if(strlen($fpname) > 10) $fname .= '...'; $fname .= '</b>';

echo $fname;
```

See [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a5cdf4052070d96c00057203879255045b7c74a2) here.